# getting 403 error in cloud armor when sending multipart/form-data as content type with JSON data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

For my react application, have configured GCP WAF security policies. While sending POST request with JSON data and Content-Type: multipart/form-data, error 'body_denied_by_security_policy' is occurring due to owasp-crs-v030001-id921150-protocolattack - HTTP Header Injection Attack via payload (CR/LF detected)(rule not added in evaluatePreconfiguredExpr() command)

Please find the request, headers and body in below image

[request, headers and body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ6z2.png)

If I disable the signatures in cloud armor policy based on  https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rule-tuning#protocol_attack, operations working fine.
**evaluatePreconfiguredExpr('protocolattack-stable', ['owasp-crs-v030001-id921150-protocolattack'])**

**Request:**

Without disabling this rule, what should I do so that my request should get success ?

Note: For non empty JSON also, 403 error occurs due to owasp-crs-v030001-id921150-protocolattack

Answer (score 0):

Try using the new Cloud Armor `[JSON parsing](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rule-tuning#apply_json_parsing_on_custom_content-type_header_values) feature that allows you to adjust the JSON MIME types that Cloud Armor will use. By default, Cloud Armor will use application/json as the MIME type which could trip the signature. By adding the custom MIME types this will give Cloud Armor additional hints about the nature of the workload it is inspecting.

Depending on what the application is doing, you also might consider giving Cloud Armor hints if there is a [cookie or header](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rule-tuning#examples) value that would indicate that you want Cloud Armor to exclude it from processing a rule or signature.  NOTE: at the time of this writing, this functionality is in public beta.